# If $f\in C^0([a,b])$ then $\int^b_a|f(x)|^pdx=0$ implies $f(x)=0$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that

> If $f\in C^0([a,b]),p\geq 1$ then $\int^b_a|f(x)|^pdx=0$ implies $f(x)=0$ $\forall x \in [a,b].$

This is how I argue:

Since $|f(x)|\geq 0$ and $f$ is continuous then the only way the integral can equal $0$ is if $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Would this be wrong or not rigorous enough?

Comment: No, not rigorous. Where did you use continuity?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do I need to use it? It is said in the definition of the function. But could you explain what exactly i'm missing?

Comment: in your proof what happens when p is 0

Comment: @Monocerotis sorry, p is bigger than 1

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ for $x \neq 0$  and $1$ for $x=0$  then $\int |f|^{p}$ exists and equals $0$ but the function is not $0$. Continuity is very important.

Comment: Why is it that the **only** way the integral can be zero is when $f\equiv 0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy well yes, so that's why it can't equal the function you proposed, since in the definition it is continous

Comment: @Sam if $f\in C^0([a,b])$ then if i'm understanding this right, $f$ is continous. So having the absolute value of $f$, it is non negative for all $x\in [a,b]$. This requires the function to be the $0$ function( otherwise no non-continuous function can meet these requirements), for the integral to be $0$

Comment: @ThePoorJew What is your definition of $C^0([a,b])?$ Also, it won't be rigorous unless you justify why "otherwise the integral can't be $0$".

Comment: @SahibaArora $C^0([a,b])$ is the space of continuous functions? Right?

Comment: @ThePoorJew It is your question. You should tell us what the notation means. The same notation is used for different things in different books.

Comment: @SahibaArora it means that the function is continuous on the interval and that it doesn't have any continuous derivatives (just checked in book)

Comment: @ThePoorJew Okay. So you need to justify why continuity implies $|f|=0$ to make it rigorous.

Comment: @SahibaArora isn't it sufficient for what i've done? What I basically did is I said that since the function is continuous and non negative, then the only way the integral of the function can be equal to $0$ is if $f=0$  for all $x$ since if the function is something else, i.e not $f=0 \forall x \in [a,b]$ then it violates the definition that is put in the first place that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @ThePoorJew Again you don't justify why "the only way the integral of the function can be equal to $0$ is if $f=0$." You need to justify why otherwise continuity would be violated.

Comment: @SahibaArora ok, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your argument was not rigorous as you didn't justify your statement: "the only way the integral can equal $0$ is if $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$."

**Proof:** Suppose there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0.$ Then $\epsilon=|f(x_0)|^p>0.$ Continuity of $f$ implies there exists $\delta>0$ such that \begin{align*}x\in[a,b],|x-x_0|<\delta &\implies ||f|^p(x)-|f|^p(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\&\implies ||f|^p(x)-\epsilon|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\&\implies|f(x)|^p>\frac{\epsilon}{2}.\end{align*}

Therefore $$\int_a^b |f(x)|^p\,dx\geq \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}|f(x)|^p\,dx>\epsilon\delta>0$$ which is a contradiction.

(Note: You can always choose $\delta>0$ small enough so that $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\subseteq [a,b].$)

Comment: just a small doubt from a student. Here $||f|^p(x)-|f|^p(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ why have you specifically chosen $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ please...

Comment: @Monocerotis Oh you could choose anything less than $\epsilon,$ just to obtain the final term is $>0.$

Comment: got it.thanks a lot!

Comment: Many compliments for your career.